# Improve Apache Spark to Redis writes performance

Tags: java, apache-spark, redis

I have an application which writes key,value data to Redis using Apache Spark. The application works without any issue. But, the application is lot slower. I am looking for some suggestions here to improve the write throughput and increase the parallelism while writing the data to Redis.

Here, is the code

```
Dataset<Row> rowkeyMapping = services.select(regexp_replace(col("rowkey"), "_", "").as("rowkey"),struct(regexp_replace(col("name"), "\\[", ","), regexp_replace(col("oname"), "\\[", ","), col("cid")).as("detailsinfo"));

rowkeyMapping.foreach(obj -> {
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(5000);
    JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "redis-host", Integer.parseInt("6379"));
    Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    String[] rowArray = obj.mkString()
        .replaceAll("[\\[]", ",")
        .split(",");
    String key = rowArray[0];
    DetailInfo detail = new DetailInfo();
    detail.setName(rowArray[1]);
    detail.setOName(rowArray[2]);
    detail.setCid(rowArray[3]);

    String value = om.writeValueAsString(detail);
    logger.info("writing key value pairs to Redis cache (Key) :: " + key);
    jedis.set(key, value);
    jedis.quit();
});
```

I have little understanding of the Redis Pipelining. But, I think Pipelining is more of batching the commands. Here, in my case, I am dealing with millions of data. I am not sure if pipelining is the best fit.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis library

Comment: Well, I tried using this library but it has a lot of issues. So, I started using the Jedis java library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on neither Spark nor Redis, but I think that the following lines should be outside the foreach loop:

```
JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
poolConfig.setMaxTotal(5000);
JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "redis-host", Integer.parseInt("6379"));
```

Comment: The problem is we cannot serialize the connection outside the foreach loop. Thats the reason why i had to instantiate withing the foreach loop.

Comment: Why can't you serialize the connection outside the foreach loop?

Comment: Because foreach is executed in the executor.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amir Kost mentioned in his answer, your problem is that you create a new connection when you set a single key-value pair. In order to improve the performance, you should reuse the connection for a batch of key-value pairs.

As you mentioned in your comment, you have to create the connection in the executor. So in order to reuse the connection, you need to use the `foreachPartition` method of `Dataset<Row>`, instead of `foreach`. `foreachPartition` runs the given `ForeachPartitionFunction<T>` function for the whole partition. So you can create a connection, and reuse it for all of items in the partition. Check the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) for detail.

Also, with `foreachPartition`, you can get a batch of items in the partition, then you can use Redis Pipline to get better performance. Check pipeline [doc](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) for detail